Jenkins unable to connect to Docker-in-Docker container: "Status 400: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server"
I'm setting up a Jenkins environment with Docker-in-Docker (DinD) for creating cloud agents, but I'm encountering an error when trying to connect Jenkins to the Docker host. I I followed the official docs of jenkins with docker, Here's my setup:

Docker-in-Docker container:

sudo docker run \                                                 
  --name jenkins-docker \   
  --restart=unless-stopped \
  --detach \
  --privileged \     
  --network jenkins \                  
  --network-alias docker \              
  --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --publish 2376:2376 \                           
  docker:dind \                                       
  --storage-driver overlay2 \


Jenkins master container:

sudo docker run \                                                 
  --name jenkins-blueocean \
  --restart=on-failure \
  --detach \
  --network jenkins \
  --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client \
  --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
  --publish 8080:8080 \
  --publish 50000:50000 \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  myjenkins-blueocean:2.462.2-1

When I try to create cloud (docker) agents in Jenkins and test the connection to the Docker host using the URI tcp://docker:2376, the test fails with this error:
Status 400: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.BadRequestException: Status 400: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.

The Docker daemon logs show that it's starting correctly and listening on the expected ports:
time="2024-10-01T15:36:24.175616301Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
time="2024-10-01T15:36:24.175641634Z" level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2376"

here is the log file of jenkins if you think it could help:
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: /var/jenkins_home/war
2024-10-01 15:55:13.331+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2024-10-01 15:55:13.495+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2024-10-01 15:55:13.608+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-10.0.20; built: 2024-01-29T20:46:45.278Z; git: 3a745c71c23682146f262b99f4ddc4c1bc41630c; jvm 17.0.12+7
2024-10-01 15:55:14.167+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2024-10-01 15:55:14.246+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: Session workerName=node0
2024-10-01 15:55:15.062+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2024-10-01 15:55:15.333+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@41e1455d{Jenkins v2.462.2,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
2024-10-01 15:55:15.360+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@c03cf28{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2024-10-01 15:55:15.384+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started Server@41e1e210{STARTING}[10.0.20,sto=0] @2896ms
2024-10-01 15:55:15.387+0000 [id=26]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2024-10-01 15:55:15.926+0000 [id=32]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2024-10-01 15:55:16.408+0000 [id=33]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2024-10-01 15:55:27.853+0000 [id=35]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
2024-10-01 15:55:27.922+0000 [id=33]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
2024-10-01 15:55:27.995+0000 [id=36]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
2024-10-01 15:55:29.567+0000 [id=31]    INFO    h.p.b.g.GlobalTimeOutConfiguration#load: global timeout not set
2024-10-01 15:55:30.733+0000 [id=37]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config loaded
2024-10-01 15:55:30.742+0000 [id=37]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config adapted
2024-10-01 15:55:30.945+0000 [id=34]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs
2024-10-01 15:55:30.948+0000 [id=34]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated
2024-10-01 15:55:31.197+0000 [id=32]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2024-10-01 15:55:31.576+0000 [id=25]    INFO    hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle#onReady: Jenkins is fully up and running
2024-10-01 15:55:35.668+0000 [id=64]    INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 16:00:35.661+0000 [id=101]   INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 16:00:38.642+0000 [id=58]    INFO    i.j.docker.client.DockerAPI#getOrMakeClient: Cached connection io.jenkins.docker.client.DockerAPI$SharableDockerClient@40439feb to DockerClientParameters{dockerUri='tcp://docker:2376', credentialsId='null', readTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000, connectTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000}
2024-10-01 16:05:35.756+0000 [id=122]   INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 16:10:35.687+0000 [id=143]   INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 16:15:35.695+0000 [id=164]   INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 16:15:51.255+0000 [id=77]    INFO    i.j.docker.client.DockerAPI$1#entryDroppedFromCache: Dropped connection io.jenkins.docker.client.DockerAPI$SharableDockerClient@40439feb to DockerClientParameters{dockerUri='tcp://docker:2376', credentialsId='null', readTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000, connectTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000}
2024-10-01 16:15:51.499+0000 [id=77]    INFO    i.j.docker.client.DockerAPI#getOrMakeClient: Cached connection io.jenkins.docker.client.DockerAPI$SharableDockerClient@71f9f17f to DockerClientParameters{dockerUri='tcp://172.18.0.3:2376', credentialsId='null', readTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000, connectTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000}
2024-10-01 16:18:52.945+0000 [id=18]    INFO    i.j.docker.client.DockerAPI#getOrMakeClient: Cached connection io.jenkins.docker.client.DockerAPI$SharableDockerClient@9f53e52 to DockerClientParameters{dockerUri='tcp://docker:2376', credentialsId='null', readTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000, connectTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000}
2024-10-01 16:20:35.665+0000 [id=185]   INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 16:24:48.016+0000 [id=27]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: JVM is terminating. Shutting down Jetty
2024-10-01 16:24:48.128+0000 [id=27]    INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStop: Stopped Server@41e1e210{STOPPING}[10.0.20,sto=0]
2024-10-01 16:24:48.436+0000 [id=27]    INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStop: Stopped ServerConnector@c03cf28{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2024-10-01 16:24:48.863+0000 [id=27]    INFO    hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle#onStatusUpdate: Stopping Jenkins
2024-10-01 16:24:49.392+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins$16#onAttained: Started termination
2024-10-01 16:24:49.638+0000 [id=27]    INFO    h.p.b.global.Lifecycle#shutdown: Shutdown complete - Global TimeOut ScheduledExecutorService had 0 tasks pending
2024-10-01 16:24:49.702+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins$16#onAttained: Completed termination
2024-10-01 16:24:49.702+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#_cleanUpDisconnectComputers: Starting node disconnection
2024-10-01 16:24:49.912+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#_cleanUpShutdownPluginManager: Stopping plugin manager
2024-10-01 16:24:50.064+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#_cleanUpPersistQueue: Persisting build queue
2024-10-01 16:24:50.122+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.model.Jenkins#_cleanUpAwaitDisconnects: Waiting for node disconnection completion
2024-10-01 16:24:50.123+0000 [id=27]    INFO    hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle#onStatusUpdate: Jenkins stopped
2024-10-01 16:24:50.162+0000 [id=27]    INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStop: Stopped w.@41e1455d{Jenkins v2.462.2,/,null,STOPPED}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: /var/jenkins_home/war
2024-10-01 16:50:43.177+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2024-10-01 16:50:43.308+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2024-10-01 16:50:43.408+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-10.0.20; built: 2024-01-29T20:46:45.278Z; git: 3a745c71c23682146f262b99f4ddc4c1bc41630c; jvm 17.0.12+7
2024-10-01 16:50:43.890+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2024-10-01 16:50:43.963+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: Session workerName=node0
2024-10-01 16:50:44.877+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2024-10-01 16:50:45.082+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@6bff19ff{Jenkins v2.462.2,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
2024-10-01 16:50:45.108+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@c03cf28{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2024-10-01 16:50:45.130+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started Server@41e1e210{STARTING}[10.0.20,sto=0] @2845ms
2024-10-01 16:50:45.132+0000 [id=26]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2024-10-01 16:50:45.556+0000 [id=32]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2024-10-01 16:50:45.967+0000 [id=35]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2024-10-01 16:50:52.631+0000 [id=32]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
2024-10-01 16:50:52.696+0000 [id=38]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
2024-10-01 16:50:52.729+0000 [id=38]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
2024-10-01 16:50:54.164+0000 [id=33]    INFO    h.p.b.g.GlobalTimeOutConfiguration#load: global timeout not set
2024-10-01 16:50:54.757+0000 [id=38]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config loaded
2024-10-01 16:50:54.759+0000 [id=38]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config adapted
2024-10-01 16:50:54.898+0000 [id=35]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs
2024-10-01 16:50:54.936+0000 [id=38]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated
2024-10-01 16:50:55.010+0000 [id=36]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2024-10-01 16:50:55.136+0000 [id=25]    INFO    hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle#onReady: Jenkins is fully up and running
2024-10-01 16:51:09.580+0000 [id=73]    INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 16:56:09.577+0000 [id=94]    INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 17:01:09.581+0000 [id=123]   INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 17:01:31.902+0000 [id=18]    INFO    i.j.docker.client.DockerAPI#getOrMakeClient: Cached connection io.jenkins.docker.client.DockerAPI$SharableDockerClient@6531d79e to DockerClientParameters{dockerUri='tcp://docker:2376', credentialsId='null', readTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000, connectTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000}
2024-10-01 17:06:09.605+0000 [id=144]   INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents
2024-10-01 17:11:09.577+0000 [id=165]   INFO    c.n.j.p.d.DockerContainerWatchdog#execute: Skipping unconfigured Docker Cloud docker-agents


DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 vs --volume /var/run/docker.sock so decide, is docker available in tcp://docker or in docker.sock? Why use both? the test fails with this error: What test? What is the docker image you are trying to use? Are you using custom container registry?

This part of the log is relevant
DockerClientParameters{dockerUri='tcp://docker:2376', credentialsId='null', readTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000, connectTimeoutInMsOrNull=60000}

See that credentialsId='null'? Jenkins thinks your docker API port doesn't have certs and listens for http requests, not https. You mounted /certs/client to your Jenkins container for a reason - it needs to be configured in Jenkins.
